# centering content while having a side-bar on the left

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I have a fixed nav-bar on the top and a fixed side-bar on the left.
The content should be in the middle. `margin: auto` in this case with the side-bar on the left doesn't do the trick.

The problem is, that `margin: auto` does not consider the width of the side-bar.

The div, which should contain the content and must be centered has more space on the right side, than on the left side (the side-bar is on the left side)

[image].

There is also the link to the code: https://codepen.io/arnameti/pen/RwpmoQJ

Then i tried with `width: calc(auto - 'width of side-nav')`, but i realized that the calc-function doesn't acceppt `auto` as a value.

I've tried a lot to solve by puting a ***div*** around and using ***flex-box***.
Unfortunately, i don't get the desired result and i am now in the situation where i need help or advice.

Comment: You can set the position of the div.main-content to relative and adjust its left position based on the actual width of the fixed sidebar. You may need to adjust the z-index of the header and the content container after doing this.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your code needs to be presented _here_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `.main-content` has a fixed width of 1500px, you could use this setting on `.main-content` instead of `margin-auto`:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 750px + 1.25vh + 1.25vw);
```

That's half of the full width minus half of the width of `.main-content` plus half of the width of the fixed sidebar. This positions the element exactly in the middle.

`margin-right` remains undefined.

Of course this isn't responsive, but your fixed width content element isn't responsive anyway. You could use media queries with similarly calculated settings for smaller widths.